# specify the location of logs using Logger.java

Tags: java

I have a logger code in Java. It is not creating a log file. Though when I am using Logger.println in another class it is printing. But I am not sure if it is logging or not.

I have written a logger class and I am using this in another class to log my code.

My logger class looks like below:

```
 public class Logger{
private static String logFile=null;


public static boolean setLogFile(String newLogFile, Boolean b){
boolean done = false;

if (logFile ==null){
logFile = newLogFile;
File file = new File(logFile);
try{
    done = file.createNewFile();
   }
   catch(IOException e){Logger.println("Error in creating log file" +logFile);
 }
 }
 else {
 File fromFile = new File(logFile);
 File toFile = new File(newLogFile);
 if(fromFile.exists()){
 done = fromFile.renameTo(tofile);
 if (done){
         logFile = newLogFile;
 }
  else{
 logger.println("can not move file");
}
}else{
Logger.println("file not exist";
}}
return done;
}

public static void print(String data){
system.out.println(data);
 try{
FileWriter logger = new FileWriter (logFile, true);
logger.write(data);
logger.close();
 }
catch(IOException e){System.out.println("can not write to file");
}}
```

where is logger.print saving to?
where are the logs being saved or how can i specify the location of my logs?

Comment: **Why** are none of the existing `Logger` implementations sufficient?

Comment: If you don't want any external dependencies, there is always the [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: _"My logger class looks like below:"_ — this can't possibly be your actual Logger class, as it is full of errors. There is no `Logger.println` method which you mention; You have `toFile` and `tofile`, and among other things, `system.out.println` which should be `System.out.println`. The code you present in your question can't be compiled. You should _copy_ and _**paste**_ your _actual_ code to avoid mis-typing, and to avoid omitting necessary details.

Answer (score 2):

You no need to reinvent the wheel again. You can easily integrate one of the loggers that can write a log file at your convenient location.

Try Log4j, SL4j or available dependencies based on your need.

These existing implementations give you fine-grained loggings. You can print info, error, debug, config and warnings. It would be easier to integrate as well as developer can concentrate on business logic.